# Code Igniter Fatal Error ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following code that has been working perfectly for a few months, and all of a sudden it has stopped working. I checked the query being run and it is working correctly and getting the intended results.

This is the code:

```
$this->db->where('user', $user);
$this->db->select_max('id', 'max_id');
$query1 = $this->db->get('offers');

$result = $query1->row();
```

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object
```

Comment: You porbably have an sql error and `db_debug` disabled in `application/config/database.php`. In that case the `->get()` will just return `false`. Do you get any error with `db_debug` enabled?

Comment: Good call! It looks like there is an error:

Error Number: 2006

MySQL server has gone away

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980004/2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-in-wamp

Comment: I had some problems with a similar error that occurred occasionally on my local host. It seemed to be caused by persistant connection to the database. I solved it by setting pconnect to false in the database.php config file.